# Is there an C# equivalent to the PHP function `parse_str`?

Tags: c#, php, parsing

Is there an `C#` equivalent to the `PHP` function `parse_str`?

I couldn't find anything and wrote my own function but is there something in the `C#` framework?

```
public Dictionary<string, string> parse_str(string query) {

    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach(string set in query.Trim('?').Split('&'))
        data.Add(set.Split('=')[0], set.Split('=').Length < 2 ? "" : set.Split('=')[1]);

    return data;
}​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* you are [looking](http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+parse+application/x-www-form-urlencoded) for [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I knew it. Why does it seem PHP's manual is easier to navigate and discover than C#'s? Thanks!

Comment: Google is your C# manual/MS documentation in general search utility - you just have to know what to search for, which is not always easy. It helps to add a `site:msdn.microsoft.com` clause you your Google search term

Comment: Unfortunately the `NameValueCollection` doesn't `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize` like a `Dictionary<string,string>` does. And it would seem the only way to convert `NameValueCollection` to a `Dictionary<string,string>` would be a for loop which makes my `parse_str` function more relevant. C# < PHP for web development.

Answer (score 2):

If you're taking it from the browser's query string, you can use `Request.QueryString`

You can get a list of all the keys: `Request.QueryString.Keys`

Get a value of a key: `Request.QueryString["KeyName"]`

Comment: I figured you were overlooking that the querystring was already parsed for you and that you may want to use `Request.QueryString` over retrieving it and passing it into `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.  Can you explain how this is irrelevant?

Comment: It covers the 95% use case much better than any alternative, despite not having identical functionality to what was asked.  It's rather uncommon for a site to parse the query strings of a page other than 'itself'.

Comment: Can you look up [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) mentioned in the question and explain how your answer was relevant.

Comment: @iambriansreed C# is not php.  You're not always going to find an exact port for everything.  Rather than looking for, "how what C# code does the same thing as this PHP code" you should be asking, "how do I accomplish this *task* in C#".  If the answers happen to be the same, so be it.

Comment: @Servy explained the reason for my answer better than I could have.

Comment: @iambriansreed He answered the question that you should have asked, and addressed the underlying problem rather than the specific technical question.  That gets a +1 in my book.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry, I should have stated clearly at the beginning why your answer was not only wrong but irrelevant. I referenced the `parse_str` function because it does what exactly what I need. @DaveRandom didn't assume my lack of knowledge and answered the question. He didn't think my question was wrong and should be fixed. Just because you may have never had the need to parse a string into variables doesn't mean the rest of the web developer world hasn't. Please think twice before assuming my question is wrong. Thanks for attempt.

Comment: @iambriansreed I am only responding in hopes to educate you in your error.  You did not post a "wrong" question and I did not post a "wrong" answer.  The only action which was wrong, was your choice to downvote my answer.  My answer can be helpful to people who ask a similar question to yours, but are not looking for the specific answer you are.  Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down